# Enable Remote connections on SQL Server 2005 command line

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, command-line, telnet, remote-connection

A client I'm working with needs his SQL Server 2005 to accept remote connections, but I've only got a telnet shell to work with. I can't get any GUI on this remote computer, only a command shell.

So, is it possible, in any way, to enable remote connections on it ?

I've tried `sqlcmd` in my shell, but even when I'm specifying `localhost` as the address, it says that remote connections aren't allowed.

Any help would be great :)

Comment: How was SQL Server installed?  Is this SQLEXPRESS?  The error message about remote connections not being enabled is just a suggestion about a possible root cause; you'll get the same error if SQL Server is not running or the wrong instance name is specified.

Comment: They are working with the Standard 2005 edition on a Windows 2003 server. I've already got sysadmin credentials, but isn't localhost enough for the instance name? And sorry, but it's a bit fuzzy in my head, I'm not used to work with this :(

Comment: Yes, localhost alone should be enough to connect locally using the shared memory protocol to the default instance.  Are you sure the SQL Server service is running (e.g. "sc query MSSQLSERVER")?

Comment: That was so obvious that I forgot to check it. I will keep you updated ASAP!  Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

Okay I definitely feel bad :D
When I saw the SQL server installation, I assumed they were using it but they weren't... 
It was just another type of database.

Anyway, thanks for your help and for your time!